# How do I conveniently install LaTeX packages?

Tags: packages

I am trying to install a LaTeX package:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox

How do I efficiently install it? Right now, I am just downloading each file one at a time from the page. Next, I think I have to meticulously place certain files into various folders on my Mac ...

Comment: This looks very like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437: does that help? If so, I am minded to mark this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [TeX Live Utility](http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/), a tool that's included in [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/).

Comment: That link is dead.

Comment: I updated the link.